# Does every Zigbee module support 868MHz

Tags: zigbee

The zigbee alliance mentions that he zigbee phy supports 868MHz and 2.4GHz.
Does this mean that every Zigbee module supports this. Or do i need a dedicated 868MHz zigbee module?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about hardware specs and not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Zigbee hardware would operate at just one of the two frequencies. Most of the hardware I'm familiar with runs at 2.4GHz. Read the spec on the hardware you're visiting to know for sure.